# Google Sheets query ("SELECT A WHERE B <> '0'")

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I have a table for event planning where A is the items and B is the quantities.

I then want it to turn into a list where it just has the items if B is more than 0. I have tried using `=QUERY(Job!A3:B16, SELECT A WHERE B <> '0')` but I get `#VALUE!` back and the error pop up says

> In Array Literal, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Is there a better formula to use or a better way to use this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=QUERY(Job!A3:B16, "SELECT A WHERE B <> 0 ")
```

you can also use FILTER

```
=FILTER(Job!A3:A16,Job!B3:B16<>0)
```